# Showing that $J \subset J' \iff J/I \subset J'/I$ where $I,J$ and $J'$ are ideals of a ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose that $I$ is an ideal of a ring $R$. If $J$ and $J'$ are ideals of $R$ that contain $I$ I am trying to show that:

$J\subset J' \iff J/I \subset J'/I$

My attempt (I only struggle with the one case of assuming the RHS and then showing the LHS so I'll only show this one):

Suppose $a \in J$, then $(a+I) \in R/J$ but by hypothesis $J/I \subset J'/I$ and so $(a+I) \in J'/I$ which means that $a\in J'$ since $J'/I = \{j+I|j\in J'\}$.

I am new to ideals and rings, so I would just like to check if my reasoning is making sense, so I apologize if this is very trivial and/or very wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to prove that $$J\subset J'\iff J/I\subset J'/I$$
as set but as ideal, which is totally different.

**Hint**

Let $f:A\longrightarrow  B$ an onto ring homomorphism.

**1)** Prove that $J$ is an ideal of $A$ $\implies f(J)$ is an ideal of $B$.

**2)** Prove that $f^{-1}(L)$ is an ideal of $A$ if $L$ is an ideal of $B$ (notice that here $f$ doesn't need to be onto).

Now, by group theory, you know that the canonical projection $$\pi: J'\longrightarrow J'/I$$
induce a bijection between $$\{\text{Subgroup of }J'\text{ that contain I}\}\quad\text{and} \quad\{\text{Subgroup of }J'/I\}.$$

To solve your problem, for $\implies $, if $J$ is an ideal that contain $I$, by **1)** $\pi(J)$ is an ideal of $J'/I$. For $\Longleftarrow$, by **2)**, if $L$ is an ideal of $J'/I$ then $\pi^{-1}(L)$ is an ideal of $J'$.

To prove both, use 1) and 2).